# Webform update from 5.3.0 to 6.1.0 results in directory error

Tags: 8, webforms

After I updated my webform module from 5.3.0 to 6.1.0 I received an error when submitting my form. Apparently it isn't able to copy the pdf file which I added to the form and so it is blocking the submit and giving me a white page.

Here's what I have in my recent log entry:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException:
The specified file 'private://webform/saisie_du_bilan/_sid_/projet-985.pdf' could not be copied because the destination directory is not properly configured.
This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions.
in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 846 of /home/acelys/www/uno-test.agglonet.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

What does the phrase : `could not be copied because the destination directory is not properly configured` mean?
I searched on Internet without success.

I also looked into the file permissions and it is 775.

**SOLVED:** I needed to give full permission `chmod -R 777 webform` to the `private/webform` directory (private directory is created outside the $root_dir which is the /web directory).

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Drupal Answers! Did you check the permissions on both the temporary and the final destination directory?

Comment: Hi ! thank you! @berliner , the final destination file yes, the tmp i don't know where it is, do you have an idea where it is ? Thanks.

Comment: You can find that out on the file system config page: `/admin/config/media/file-system`

Comment: @berliner i have looked into it, it is well configured,
I'm wondering if it is a problem in the new version of webform, which needs the path to be defined differently ...

Comment: I have little experience with webform, so I can't say anything about that. But you can debug a bit to see which directory it's complaining about. Unless you're already on Drupal 9 (which I assume you are not), you can add a debug statement to https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.9.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php#L484 which is where that error message originates.

Comment: **SOLVED**: I needed to give full permission `chmod -R 777 webform` to the private/webform directory  (private directory is created outside the $root_dir: /web/ dir)